# What's the meaning of 制限時間 来ちゃうから?

Tags: translation

I think it's say: "I'll come for a limit of time?" but I'm unsure about this

Comment: Some more context might help

Comment: "I'll come for a limit of time" doesn't make any sense, so it's not clear what you think it means (although whatever it is, it is probably incorrect).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My hunch is "It's about time" or "It's high time".

Then, grammar

"ちゃう" is a verb used in casual speech of "しまう" which is often used for unintended actions.

Therefore "来ちゃう" means as same as "来てしまう”.

Hence, I guess it means when you are talking with someone else

"We need to hurry up. The time limit is coming."

or in your head

"I should hurry up. The time limit is coming."

But, for sure I need more context to determine what this sentence wants to say.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I'd translate this as "Because the time limit (will) come".

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

> 'time is almost up' or
>    'time is running out' or
>    'time will run out'

for more natural English depending upon the context.